# Usage of a date index in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which retrieves shipment information.

I would like to be able to use an index on a date column. The where clause for this column looks like `shipment.end_alloc_date >= to_date( last week )`. 
When I add `shipment.end_alloc_date <= to_date( next week )` the index is used. However, I don't want to use this second line.

Does anyone know how to force Oracle to use this date index with only using the first restriction?

---

The table contains about 180.000 rows and both sql retrieve 50 rows. However, when I run explain plan the index on end_alloc_date is only used in the second sql. How come and is there something I can do to force Oracle to use the index?

1) `select <some data> from shipment where shipment.end_alloc_date >= to_date( last week )`

2) `select <some data> from shipment where shipment.end_alloc_date >= to_date( last week ) and shipment.end_alloc_date <= to_date( next week )`

Comment: Just curious. Why you need this behavior?

Comment: Not sure... you could look into index hints, but since they're *hints*, I don't think they ever *guarantee 100%* that the behaviour you will want will actually be used. But it *might* be. ;) The other option might be a function-based index on that expression...

Comment: how big is the shipment table and how many results do you expect?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Hints are a misnomer; they're not hints, they're directives.  A properly formatted hint completely overrides the optimizer.

Comment: did u build stats?  Also, maybe Oracle is smarter than u? (if query returns a big chunk of data, maybe FTS is better).  also, I assume "end_alloc_date" is actually a date, and not a varchar2.  Finally, show the actual SQL not pseudo code would be more helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, you should trust the optimizer to know its business, which is optimizing the performance of queries.  In particular, you should expect that the optimizer knows when it will be beneficial to use an index and when it will not be beneficial to do so.  If using an index won't benefit the performance of the query, then the optimizer won't use it.

So, some questions for you:

1. Is the query running too slow?  (If not, why are you worried?)
2. What is the schema of the tables?
3. What are the indexes on the tables?
4. What are the cardinalities of the tables in question?
5. What exactly does the complete query look like?
6. What does the query plan look like?
7. What proportion of the rows in the table satisfy `shipment.end_alloc_date >= to_date(last week)`?
8. What proportion of the rows in the table satisfy `shipment.end_alloc_date <= to_date(next week)`?

Did you notice that these conditions are not inverses of each other?  I assume so, but that means that the best query plan for one may be different from the best query plan for the other.

The optimizer will be taking into account the answers to questions 2-8 in that list, and using its judgement to choose the best way of answering the query. You must know the answers to these questions if you think the optimizer is failing.  But without that information, no-one here can provide you much help beyond vague hand-waving "look for optimizer hints in the manual".

Answer (score 4):

It is a misconception that using the index is the fastest way to run a query.

I expect the Optimizer has decided its more efficient to not use the index when only 'shipment.end_alloc_date >= to_date( last week )' is specified.

For example, if that query yields many rows then most likely the optimizer has chosen this route because its more efficient **not** to use the index. It could choose a full table scan instead because its quicker to read contigious blocks of data as opposed to reading rowids from the index.